# Ionic 6 capacitor 4 iOS app TinyMCE editor referrer header missing issue

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, tinymce, capacitor

I created an **iOS app using Ionic 6, Capacitor 4, and Angular 15**. TinyMCE editor has a referer header missing issue in the iOS app (see screenshot attachment)

For the editor, I used the "**@tinymce/tinymce-angular**": "7.0.0" npm package.

I tried the following solutions but they didn't work:

1. Added the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key with a value of true in the Info.plist file
2. Added NSAppTransportSecurity and NSExceptionDomains in the Info.plist file
3. Added "data-referrer": "http://example.com" option in the editor init config
4. Added "referrer" meta in the index.html file - added script

How can I solve this issue? Thank you in advance.

[image]